# VB.NET variable date and time

Tags: vb.net, datetime, variables

I need help to save date and time into 1 variable to save in SQL params.

```
I have textbox (txBulan) = "1",
textbox (txTahun) = "2016",
double (k) = "2",
string (time) = "13:00:00"
```

And i want to save into 1 variable with format `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`.

```
dim CI as datetime

CI = CDate(Format((txBulan.Text & "/" & k-1 & "/" & CDbl(txTahun.Text) & " " & time), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I am not quite understand how does those text boxes and the `k` works, I recommend you could use a `new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` to create a DateTime variable.

```
Dim txYear as TextBox ' Assume Text = 2016
Dim txMonth as TextBox ' Assume Text = 1
Dim txDay as TextBox ' Assume Text = 2
Dim time as String = "13:00:00"
Dim Hour as Integer = -1
Dim Minute as Integer = -1
Dim Second as Integer = -1

For Each piece as String in time.Split(":")
    ' For safety, add try-catch
    If (Hour < 0) Then
        Hour = Integer.Parse(piece)
    Else If (Minute < 0) Then
        Minute = Integer.Parse(piece)
    Else
        Second = Integer.Parse(piece)
    End If
End For

' For safety, cast .Text to integer value
Dim Ci AS New DateTime(
    Integer.Parse(txYear.Text),
    Integer.Parse(txMonth.Text),
    Integer.Parse(tx.Day.Text),
    Hour, Minute, Second
)
Dim DateString as String = Ci.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: There's no constructor overload for `DateTime` that takes a `string` for the year, month, and day.

Comment: Sorry, too lazy to cast it plus VB.net accept it anyway :P

Comment: VB will only accept if you're not using Option Strict, which is poor practice.

Comment: @ZayLau - You should always assume that any VB.NET code on SO has `Option Strict On` and you should answer accordingly.